# What resolution can a graphics card handle in multiple monitors?

Tags: display, graphics-card, multiple-monitors

So given a graphics card (in my case [AMD Radeon HD 6620G](http://www.notebookcheck.net/AMD-Radeon-HD-6620G.54675.0.html) on a [Toshiba Satellite P775D](http://www.toshiba.com/us/computers/laptops/satellite/P770/P775D-S7302)) how do you know what your laptop can handle when you have multiple monitors? I’d like to know in general how you answer questions like:

1. Can I attach a 2560x1440 monitor display?
2. Can I attach 2 1080p screens?

etc. Please let me know the general principles & web resources for how you figure this out. Thanks!